# Ntrip client not receiving RTCM corrections

Tags: python, sockets, gps

I'm searching for help understanding how to develope a complete and functional NTRIP Client in order to receive RTCM corrections.
I'm using Python 3.4, for now on Windows 7. Searching the net, I found some sample code and I used it to write a basic client. The problem is... it doesn't work.

I have access to a rtk correction service. The service is active and functioning.

This is a snippet of my code.

```
dummyNMEA = "$GPGGA,143741.356,7839.493,S,07627.626,W,0,00,,,M,,M,,*45"

username = my_username    #username for RTCM correction service
password = my_password    #password for RTCM correction service
port = 2101    #port for the service

'''Generate an encoding of the username:password for the service.
The string must be first encoded in ascii to be correctly parsed by the
base64.b64encode function.'''
pwd = base64.b64encode("{}:{}".format(username, password).encode('ascii'))

#The following decoding is necessary in order to remove the b' character that
#the ascii encoding add. Othrewise said character will be sent to the net and misinterpreted.
pwd = pwd.decode('ascii')

print("Header sending... \n")

header =\
"GET /mountpoint HTTP/1.1\r\n" +\
"Host my_host\r\n" +\
"Ntrip-Version: Ntrip/1.0\r\n" +\
"User-Agent: ntrip.py/0.1\r\n" +\
"Accept: */*" +\
"Connection: close\r\n" +\
"Authorization: Basic {}\r\n\r\n".format(pwd)

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((my_host,int(port)))
s.send(header.encode('ascii'))

print("Waiting answer...\n")
data = s.recv(2048).decode('ascii')
print(data)

s.send(dummyNMEA.encode('ascii'))
data = s.recv(2048).decode('ascii')
print(data)

s.close()
```

Now, the code is partially funcitoning. The request goes to the rtk server and I am correctly authenticated. I receive the correct answer as from ntrip protocol:

ICY 200 OK
Server: "Server of the mountpoint"
Date: "The date"

After this, I have to send a NMEA GGA sentence, in order to start receiving the RTCM corrections. I created various dummy NMEA sentences with a generator and tested sending them. I send the sentence and.... nothing happens. I receive no answer from the server.

Somebody has some idea? Perhaps I do something wrong when encoding the sentence?

I read that perhaps I should send the NMEA sentence continuosly, but I'm new in Python programming and I am not sure how to do that with sockets.

English is not my mother language, so please excuse my errors :)

Thnak you everyone.

Comment: I am trying to do the same. I think the problem with your code is that you are sending the plain NMEA message, and what you should send is RTCM frames containing the NMEA message (at least, this is what RTKLIB internally does). Which app from RTKLIB are you using to do this? It works for me with rtkrcv (rtknavi in windows), but I wonder if the same could be done with str2str (strsvr). My problem is that since some Ntrip casters require to get your GPGGA sentences, I don't know how to bypass them when using str2str

Answer (score 1):

When you are sending the GGA is it a position that has coverage on your rtk correction service?  I have done this before, sent dummy positions that are outside the network coverage and nothing was returned, not even an error message, just no corrections.

Cheers,
Steve.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The dummy used were retrieved from the gps of my smartphone, so I think they were in the corverage area of the network. I bypassed the problem using rtklib, which implements what I needed. Unfortunately in the near future I cannot do further tests of that piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `'\r\n'` to the end of the NMEA string.

`dummyNMEA = "$GPGGA,143741.356,7839.493,S,07627.626,W,0,00,,,M,,M,,*45\r\n"`

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an Header for the NMEA as well.

```
dummyHeader = \
        "Ntrip-GGA: {}\r\n".format(dummyNMEA)
```

Then you should get an answer.